# IF equals or clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-null

I have a stored procedure that runs two separate queries and puts the data into two temporary tables. I then have an IF statement below that, depending on the outcome will display one of the two tables.

```
DECLARE @DATASET1 AS FLOAT
DECLARE @DATASET2 AS FLOAT

SET @DATASET1 = (SELECT SUM(PREM) FROM #Prem1)
SET @DATASET2 = (SELECT SUM(PREM) FROM #Prem2)

IF (@DATASET1 = 0)
BEGIN

    SELECT  DATE,
            SUM(PREM) AS PREM
    FROM #DATASET2
    GROUP BY YEAR, MONTH, DATE
    ORDER BY YEAR, MONTH

END

IF (@DATASET2 = 0)
BEGIN

    SELECT  DATE,
            SUM(PREM) AS PREM
    FROM #DATASET1 
    GROUP BY YEAR, MONTH, DATE
    ORDER BY YEAR, MONTH

END
```

This was working well until I hit some output on dataset1 that didn't produce 0 but just produced no data at all.

So I was wondering if it is possible to update this part of the query to almost say:

```
IF (@DATASET1 = 0 or '')
```

I have tried something like that but doesn't seem to work, hence my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your scalar aggregate query (`SELECT SUM(PREM) FROM #Prem1`) will return a `NULL` value if there is no record in the table or of column `PREM` contains only `NULL` values.

You can handle `NULL` with `IS NULL`, like so:

```
IF (@DATASET1 IS NULL OR @DATASET1 = 0)
```

You can also use `COALESCE()`:

```
IF (COALESCE(@DATASET1, 0) = 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by using [ISNULL()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_isnull.asp)

```
IF (ISNULL(@DATASET1, 0) = 0)
```

> Syntax: ISNULL(expression, value)
>
> ```
> Parameter           Description
> expression          Required. The expression to test whether is NULL
> value Required.     The value to return if expression is NULL
> ```